# Logout issue in TabBar based app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

This is quite a common question, but after trying a lot to fix the issue, finally I have decided to post it on StackOverFlow.com

I have a tab bar based app. The tab bar is loaded in AppDelegate.m as follows:

```
  self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2 , viewController3 , viewController4 , viewController5];
```

My 5th tab has a button for logout. When user clicks logout, I want to clear/reset entire app and go to login page which is a modalviewcontroller.

I have tried following while logging out:

```
 NSMutableArray * vcs = [NSMutableArray
                        arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
[vcs removeAllObjects ];//ObjectAtIndex:4];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:vcs];
```

This removes all views from tab-bar. But when I login again, nothing is displayed. I want to show my home screen, i.e. tab item 1 selected by default.

I have read that its not a good practice to call didFinishLaunchingWithOptions again manually.

Is there a way where I can reset all tab-bars and reinitialise them again ?

This will help me solving one more problem that is linked with this situation. When user logs out and log in again, and view controllers are not cleared, then logout page is shown again after login. And not the home view controller.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to start over, you should put a method, lets call it -(void)setupTabBarController, in the app delegate, and at start up you would call it from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. Later when you want to reset, call that method again from the login page. This method would have the creation of all the tab bar controller's view controllers in it, as well as setting the tab bar controller as the root view controller of the window.

However, it's not really clear that you need to do this, depending on what state all those controllers are in at logout time. Your problem with the logout page being shown again could probably be fixed in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing is showing because you removed the views and never added them back in.

There is no need to remove the view controllers from the tab bar after you log out. You can just write a method to reset all the data in each view controller and then set the selected tab to what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is not really an answer to your question, but this could maybe help you too (and as I can't comment on post yet i have to post it like this :)).

I had some problems with "resetting" the navigation stack when the user logs out in my tabbar app too. In the beginning I had my tabbar-controller as the root controller and was displaying the login-screen modally but than it was quiet hard reset the navigation stack once the user loged out.
What I ended up doing and it works for me quiet well is, I set the login controller as root controller and after log in displayed the tab navigation modally. On log out I simply dismiss the tabbar-controller again - everything starts from the beginning again. 
Maybe you could try this and see if it is easier to handle.

Comment: Modal views are temporary views that appear when something requires the user’s attention or when additional choices or functionality need to be offered. Using a modal view as the main view of an app is incorrect use of it.

Comment: Actually before loading modal view, my entire app is loaded.

Comment: @rocky: hmm... a college of mine, how is quiet experienced in ios dev said suggested this method to me. well, i think i will have to do more research then. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be add tabBar controller on second view controller. main view controller show home screen. when you navigate second view controller then you add tabBar here.

Comment: Make sure you add tabbar controller on self.view. After that in log out code please follow- [NavigationControllerName popToRootViewControllerAnimated:Yes];